# Why is the subscheme fixed if I fix the Hilbert Polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, hilbert-polynomial

Let $Y$ be a closed subscheme of $X=\mathbb P{^n}$ with
Hilbert Polynomial given by $h(m) =\binom{m+r}{r}$

> Prove that $Y$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^r$ embedded linearly inside $X$.

Can someone help me solve this? I know for $\mathbb P^r$ that is indeed the Hilbert Polynomial.

Edit : The context of this problem is a step towards the construction of Hilbert Schemes as done in FGA explained (chapter 2).

Looking at the Hilbert polynomial I can say that the closed subscheme has degree 1 and dimension r. Let $I$ be the ideal of $Y$, I would like to show that it is generated by a single linear polynomial(?). I tried to prove that it can't be generated by polynomials of degree greater than 1. To do this I was trying to use $h_X+h_Y= h_{X{\cup}Y}+h_{X{\cap}Y}$ but I wasn't able to show it.

Comment: Have you made any attempt of your own? What tools do you have available, or what tools are you expecting to see in a solution?

Comment: I am reading the construction of Hilbert Schemes from FGA explained (chapter 2). This shows up as an exercise. I haven't made any progress.

Comment: Luckily for you there are [other ways to improve your question to meet site standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please improve your post and I'll undelete the answer I wrote below.

Comment: I added what I said in the comments. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking me to do.

Comment: I was asking you to put a bit more effort in to your question. Your original post was lacking - it wasn't much more than "here's this problem, help". Posts like that are not well-received here (nobody upvoted it, for instance) and I don't particularly enjoy answering questions like that: it feels as if I'm being made a vending machine of mathematical knowledge, and that's not fun for me. But this problem was neat to solve, and I figured I might be able to use the solution to get you to change your behavior around here for the better. I think you can do better, I hope you rise to the occasion.

Comment: I wrote what I have tried so far. Have a look and let me know if this is the right line of thought

Comment: Thank you for improving your post. You'd need to do a bit more than showing that $I$ is generated by a single linear polynomial - that's only appropriate when $r=n-1$. I don't think directly messing about with the graded ring structure is the best way to solve this problem - the Hilbert polynomial only gives information on what happens in large enough degrees, which is hard to convert in to the sort of information you're after. I've undeleted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew that $Y\cong \Bbb P^r$, then you'd be much closer to a solution: a closed immersion $\Bbb P^r\to\Bbb P^n$ comes from a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $\Bbb P^r$ with a choice of $n+1$ global sections which generate the line bundle at every point. Such a line bundle must be $\mathcal{O}(d)$ for some $d>0$, and I claim that the degree of the image is exactly $d$: pick a hyperplane $H$ in $\Bbb P^n$ not containing $Y$ so that $\deg H\cap Y=\deg Y$ by the generalized Bezout theorem, while the degree is also $(r-1)!$ times the leading coefficient of Hilbert polynomial of $H\cap Y$. The Hilbert polynomial of $H\cap Y$ is $\binom{m+r}{r}-\binom{m+d+r}{r}=\frac{d}{(r-1)!}m^{r-1}+\cdots$ because $H$ restricts to a hypersurface on $Y$ cut out by a polynomial of degree $d$, so we must have $\deg Y=d$. As $\deg Y=1$, this shows that $Y$ must be embedded by $\mathcal{O}(1)$, which is a linear embedding.

To show $Y\cong \Bbb P^r$, we'll first show that we have a finite map $Y\to \Bbb P^r$ and then calculate that the degree of this map is 1, showing it's an isomorphism. Let $\Bbb P^{n-r-1}\subset\Bbb P^n$ be a linear $(n-r-1)$-plane which is disjoint from $Y$, and let $\Bbb P^r\subset \Bbb P^n$ be a linear $r$-plane disjoint from $\Bbb P^{n-r-1}$. Let $\pi: \Bbb P^n\setminus \Bbb P^{n-r-1}\to\Bbb P^r$ denote the projection from $\Bbb P^{n-r-1}$ to $\Bbb P^r$. I claim that $\pi$ restricts to a finite map on $Y$. First, the fiber over $p\in\Bbb P^r$ is the intersection of $Y$ with the linear $(n-r)$-plane spanned by $p$ and $\Bbb P^{n-r-1}$: this must be a dimension-zero closed subscheme of $\Bbb P^{n-r}$ for dimension reasons, as $Y$ does not intersect $\Bbb P^{n-r-1}$ while any two closed subschemes of $\Bbb P^a$ with dimensions adding to $a$ must intersect. Thus the fiber is a finite set of points, so $\pi|_Y$ is quasi-finite. But $\pi|_Y$ is also projective, and quasi-finite + projective implies finite, so $\pi|_Y$ is actually finite.

This implies that $(\pi|_Y)_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is a coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^r}$-algebras and $Y\cong \mathop{\mathbf{Spec}} (\pi|_Y)_*\mathcal{O}_Y$. If we can show that $(\pi|_Y)_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is of rank 1, then $(\pi|_Y)_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is a line bundle which will imply that $Y\cong \Bbb P^r$. As the rank of $(\pi|_Y)_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ at a point $p\in\Bbb P^r$ is the degree of the intersection of $Y$ with the $(n-r)$-plane spanned by $\Bbb P^{n-r-1}$ and $p$, we need to do a little intersection theory to show that this is 1. The following argument will do the trick:

**Claim**. If $Y\subset \Bbb P^n$ is a closed subscheme with Hilbert polynomial $h(m)=\binom{m+r}{r}$ and $L$ is a linear subspace of dimension $n-r$ so that $Y$ and $L$ intersect properly, then $Y\cap L$ is a single point (ie a point with Hilbert polynomial $1$).

*Proof*. $L$ has an ideal which is generated by $r$ linear forms $h_1,\cdots,h_r$, and $Y\cap L=Y\cap V(h_1)\cap\cdots\cap V(h_r)$, so we can prove this by induction. $Y\cap V(h_1)$ has Hilbert polynomial $\binom{r+m}{r}-\binom{r+m-1}{r}=\binom{r-1+m}{r-1}$, and by induction we see that the Hilbert polynomial of $Y\cap V(h_1)\cap\cdots\cap V(h_i)$ is $\binom{r-i+m}{r-i}$. Therefore when $i=r$ this Hilbert polynomial is just $1$ and the claim is proven.

Comment: "As the rank of (π|Y)∗OY at a point p∈Pr is the degree of the intersection of Y with the (n−r)-plane spanned by Pn−r−1 and p" - Can you elaborate why? How are we being able to talk about the rank of a pushforward by intersection of the things as you are claiming?

Comment: Finite morphisms are affine, which means that the preimage of an open affine $\operatorname{Spec} A$ on the target is an open affine $\operatorname{Spec} B$ on the source. In particular, on this local patch, the pushforward of the structure sheaf is just $B$ considered as an $A$-module. So if we want to compute the rank at a maximal ideal $m\subset A$, we just need to look at $A/m\otimes_A B\cong B/mB$. Now think about what happens if $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is a closed subscheme in $\Bbb A^n_A$ so that the finite map is induced by projection... (con't)

Comment: ... In this case, $B/mB\cong A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(I(B)+m)$, which is the exact definition of the scheme-theoretic intersection of the fiber over $m\in\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $B$ inside $\Bbb A^n_A$. Now note that this is exactly what's happening in our example: up to a change of coordinates, you can assume $\Bbb P^r$ is the linear subspace given by the vanishing of the last $n-r-1$ coordinates and $\Bbb P^{n-r-1}$ is the subspace given by the vanishing of the first $r$ coordinates. Then over $D(x_0)$ (and all the other basic affines covering $\Bbb P^r$), we get exactly the above situation!